# Finding a substring in another string

Tags: c++, string

I have to make a program that can output how many times a substring exists inside of a main string (without creating any new functions). Any ideas?

Sample of what I've done up until now:

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count=0,i,y;
    string phrase, stringtofind;

    phrase = "ANANAS";

    stringtofind = "NA";

    for (i=0;i<phrase.size();i++)
    {
        if (phrase[i] == stringtofind[1])
        {
            for (y=i+1;y<phrase.size();y++)
            {
                if (phrase[y] == stringtofind[2])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    cout << "The string NA was found " << count <<  " times in your phrase";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*without using functions*" - why? `std::string` has a `find()` method for exactly this purpose

Comment: Ae you disallowed from using library functions and can make your own functions or are all functions (excluding `main` obviously) disallowed?

Comment: Check with if and for loops then

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<string>` instead of `<string.h>` for the `std::string` class.

`std::string` begins at index 0, not 1, which means `stringtofind[1]` is wrong.

Your inner `for` loop is counting how many times the single character `stringtofind[2]` appears in `phrase`, not how many times the whole `stringtofind` string appears in `phrase`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    string phrase, stringtofind;
    bool isamatch;

    phrase = "ANANAS";

    stringtofind = "NA";

    for (size_t i = 0; (i < phrase.size()) && (phrase.size()-i) >= stringtofind.size(); )
    {
        if (phrase[i] == stringtofind[0])
        {
            isamatch = true;
            for (size_t y = 1; y < stringtofind.size(); ++y)
            {
                if (phrase[i+y] != stringtofind[y])
                {
                    isamatch = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isamatch)
            {
                ++count;
                i += stringtofind.size();
                continue;
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }   

    cout << "The string NA was found " << count <<  " times in your phrase";

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/CAeD0c)

Comment: Didnt know match was a thing thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Kontula it is just a variable, like any other. I updated my example to make that clearer.